# Github not navigating properly to the markdown header link

Tags: github, markdown

We are on Github Enterprise

I have created a md file with several headers like

```
# test
## subtest
# test1
## subtest1
# test2
## subtest2
# test3
## subtest3
```

Now when the md file is rendered in github .I create a link by right clicking on the #test 2 header and copy the link address.

I am navigated to somewhere in the content of #test header

Similarly all the header links naivgation are inconsistently behaving.

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: It seems this is not possible unless the headers have content inside them. I was messing around with it, and if you don't have much content, the page won't be able to move you to that part as it's too small.

Comment: @DavidLeal thanks for checking it...i forgot to mention that the headers have content inside them.